# ImageView display static google URL Map. How to launch maps, when Image Clicked

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

At this moment, I have an Image View that loads a URL obtained from static google maps. What I'm trying and don't find how to do, is when user clicks on image, launch google maps with the direction.
Tried it to open in a web-view, but what opens is the image and not the "map"

```
MessagingFragment.setMapOnImageClickListener(new UserClicksMapOpenURL() {
            @Override
            public void onUserClicksImageOpenMap(String url) {

                Logger.d("url");
                Intent intent=new Intent(ChatActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

The link looks like:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.934162499999985,2.552246093750014&zoom=18&size=640x640&scale=2&sensor=false&markers=color:red%7C40.934162499999985,2.552246093750014

Is there any type of intent that launch the google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shudy you can try to this it can help you.And if you want to more about google map intent then please follow this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

```
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:41.543023,2.114436");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```